# How to use a linear workflow in GIMP?

Tags: color, gimp

This question is for those who use Blender together with Gimp for post-processing, texturing, etc.

How to work in Gimp 2.10.8 as if you were working in Nuke or Blender Compositor? I'll explain:

- In Nuke or Blender, I have the possibility to linearize the input data (if these are sRGB), how can I do this in Gimp?
- In both Blender and Nuke, I can turn on and off the sRGB LUT that is applied in display, is there something like that in Gimp?
- Gimp now works at 32bit float, but are the calculations done linearly or are there limitations?
- In the output phase, how can I then return to sRGB by applying the LUT in the data?

Answer (score 1):

"Is there something like that in GIMP?" - No, and yes, kind of.

GIMP has no way to apply LUTs, at least not the in standard application itself. There may be plugins available.  Photoshop can use look up tables however.

GIMP has colour management, and soft proofing functionality, so you could technically use ICC profiles similarly.  Soft proofing can be switched on and off. I found this software which claims to convert LUTs to ICC profiles: https://www.brizsoft.com/lut-converter/lut-to-capture-one-icc-profile/
(Note: I haven't tried this so I can't vouch for it).

There's a plugin called G'MIC, which contains a film emulation filter with a user-defined option which can use HaldCLUT files, but the filter is destructive, so can't just be switched on/off. I found a reference to [this here](https://discuss.pixls.us/t/gimp-how-to-apply-3d-lut/1567/3)